# What does "!f:~0,3!" do in a command line argument in a loop?

Tags: batch-file

I know what this program does.

```bsh
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%a in (*.eml) do (
    set f=%%a
    set g=!f:~0,3!
    md "!g!" 2>nul
    move "%%a" "!g!"
)
```

but I'm confused about what exactly this argument does:

```bsh
g=!f:~0,3!
```

and this one at the end of the "md" call:

```bsh
2>nul
```

Comment: This is very broad - people here don't like being treated as a mere code explanation service with no effort from the asker. I'm sure you understand. Most of these commands can be easily Googled; can you clarify which parts you are having trouble with? Is it the  `g=!f:~0,3!` bit? (I'd be confused by that, too.)

Comment: O yes! that part and the `2>nul`

Comment: Maybe edit and clarify that those are the bits that you want an explanation for.

Comment: Okay. It's my first time to ask in a forum. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Thanks a lot in improving my question @Pekka웃

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an explanation of `set g=!f:~0,3!` open a command prompt window, run `set /?` and read the output help explaining substring referencing and delayed expansion. Take also a look on SS64 article about [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) and Microsoft article about [set](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754250.aspx).

`set g=!f:~0,3!` assigns the first 3 characters of environment variable `f` to environment variable `g` using delayed environment variable expansion.

For an explanation of `2>nul` read the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx). This code redirects every message written to second standard handle - **stderr** - to device `nul`. In other words the output of all error messages is suppressed by this code.

Command `md` (make directory) outputs an error message to **stderr** if the directory to create already exists. Another solution for `md "!g!" 2>nul` would be

```
if not exist "!g!\*" md "!g!"
```

For understanding the used commands in your batch code and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `for /?`
- `md /?`
- `move /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: Thank you so much @Mofi. It helped me a lot.